# How to read the mathematical notation for multigraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, multigraphs

How to read the mathematical notation for multigraphs:
$$E \rightarrow V \cup[V]^2 $$

$E$ is a set of edges

$V$ is the set of vertices

I am having trouble especially with this part $$[V]^2 $$

Source:

[(Reinhard Diestel, Graph Theory 5th Edition,
Springer, p.28 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz3V3.png)

> A multigraph is a pair $(V,E)$ of disjoint sets (of
>   vertices and edges) together with a map $E →V ∪ [V ]^2$ assigning to
>   every edge either one or two vertices, its ends. Thus, multigraphs too
>   can have loops and multiple edges: we may think of a multigraph as a
>   directed graph whose edge directions have been ‘forgotten’. To express
>   that $x$ and $y$ are the ends of an edge $e$ we still write $e = xy$,
>   though this no longer determines e uniquely.

(Reinhard Diestel, Graph Theory 5th Edition,
Springer, p.28 )

Comment: Can you give the source?

Comment: As @CyclotomicField suggests, knowing the source of this notation would be helpful.  That being said, the notation makes no sense to me.  Typically, $|V|$ would denote the cardinality of $V$, hence $|V|^2$ is a positive integer.  However, the set $V \cup |V|^2$ is then the union of two different kinds of objects (graph vertices and integers).  This doesn't make sense to me.  Are you sure you copied the notation correctly?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I guess I copied the notation wrong. The font in the book (or my eyes) were bad. I guess it should be a bracket.

Comment: Based on the quoted text, $[V]^2$ is the collection $\{ \{ v_1, v_2\} : v_1, v_2 \in V\}$.  This is kind of like the Cartesian product $V\times V$, but we forget the order, thus $(v_1, v_2)$ and $(v_2, v_1)$ are indistinguishable.  It seems unnecessary to me to include $V$ in this union.  This is meant to account for loops, but it seems to me that a loop from $v$ to itself could just as easily be denoted by $\{v,v\}$.

Comment: @MScott: Did you find your answer in the comments? Or is there still a need for further explanation?

Comment: @Moritz I guess Xander Hendersons answer is quiet good.